# jQuery and IE7 id issues

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I am using a "fly across" effect on my site. Like [this](http://spoonfedproject.com/wp-content/uploads/demo/jquery-slide-hover/index.htm) - The Horizontal Effect.

The script works a treat in IE8,9, FF and Chrome. When in IE7 I have more than one element on a page. Both have the same id. Hovering over the first item on the page, It loads. Hovering over the other and it doesnt work at all. Doesnt quite make sense to me.

My code is as follows :

**HTML**

```
<div style="margin-bottom:30px;" id="takealook-sub">
            <a href="#">
                <img style="left: -200px;" alt="" src="path/to/image">
            </a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
        $("#takealook-sub a").hover(function(){
            $("img", this).stop().animate({left:"0px"},{queue:false,duration:600});
        }, function() {
            $("img", this).stop().animate({left:"-200px"},{queue:false,duration:600});
        });
    });
```

Does anyone know of a reason why one would work in IE7, But not the other? Like I say all seems fine in all other browsers.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **cannot** have duplicate `id`s on a single document .... use a `class` instead ... [see the v4.0.1 HTML specs here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) and [v5 HTML specs here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute)

Example of using a class :

```
<div style="margin-bottom:30px;" class="takealook-sub">
    <a href="#">
        <img style="left: -200px;" alt="" src="path/to/image">
    </a>
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom:30px;" class="takealook-sub">
    <a href="#">
        <img style="left: -200px;" alt="" src="path/to/image">
    </a>
</div>
```

ie you can have as many as you like.... then you can do this :

```
$(function () {
    $(".takealook-sub a").hover(function () {
        $("img", this).stop().animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 600
        });
    }, function () {
        $("img", this).stop().animate({
            left: "-200px"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 600
        });
    });
});
```

in the jQuery selectors `.` is the prefix for classes instead of a `#` for `id`s

Comment: And the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: Thats great, I had a feeling multiple id's may be an issue. Is that showing that IE7 is the most compliant browser there then ;-)? Haha

Comment: @StuBlackett I would never say that any browser that starts with the latters I and E are compliant (im sweating just writing those things in the same sentence) ... i would just say the other browsers are more tolerant !

Comment: Agree with you there @ManseUK